# Subtask in its own heap space

Tags: java, memory-management, exec

In Java, supposing you want to run a task in its own heap space (e.g. so that it can crash with an out of memory error without affecting the rest of your program), you can use Runtime.exec to load the JVM and the relevant byte code files from the file system and redo all the work that needs to be done to start up a Java program from scratch.

This is somewhat high overhead, if the tasks you want to run are fairly fine-grained. Is there any lower overhead way to do it?

Comment: Perhaps the best thing to do is to write your code so it doesn't get an OOME, this avoids the need to protect your application from itself.

Comment: Not in this case - it's machine generated code, not my own handwritten code, that I'm concerned about.

Comment: Is this code generated by a third party library? If you wrote the generator for the machine generated code, shouldn't make it easier to know what code can be produced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you'd be anyways doing interprocess communication, is looking into RMI an option for you? With RMI daemon, you can have pooled processes to which you can submit jobs and get back results. This also relieves you of manually managing spawning VM's etc.

Or look into a job queue based solution in which the main VM creates job packets and dumps them on the queue which is monitored by one or more processes. Anyways, AFAIK, the most fine grained way of doing these is not spawning VM's on demand.